# Windows Azure Mobile Services: Add HTML Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-mobile-services

i developed a mobile App backend with The mobile Services (.net runtime, not node.js). Now The User requests to Do a few administrative Tasks on The backend. Of course i develop a normal Website and Let it go to The mobile backend. But i wonder if it is not simply possible to add a few Server rendered razor pages to The mobile Services Project. I mean This Sounds somehow logic to me, since it is only an Administrator backend.

is This possible?
best
Laurin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. Azure Mobile Services provides a cloud **backend** in the form of a .NET or Nodejs Web API and not a frontend.

One thing you could do (we did this for our mobile services admin page) is to create an  website using Azure Websites and then connect to your mobile services using the Azure JavaScript API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554207.aspx).

Or if you want to use AngularJS for your website you can use the excellent AngularJS service (https://github.com/TerryMooreII/angular-azure-mobile-service).

HTH,
Jeffry

Comment: Thank you. The solution is clear to me, but i wanted to be sure that there is no way to achieve this :) thanks!